# Three Curl request not submitted

Tags: php, curl

I am calling three methods which executes xml using curl

```
$clientID=$newInvoice->reateClient($name,$organization,$email,$address,$country);

$invoiceID=$newInvoice->CreateInvoice($clientID,$invoiceNumber,$itemName,$cost,$quantity);

echo $newInvoice->SendInvoice($invoiceID);
```

when I use these all three method then first executes properly but second and third shows error that : String could not be parsed as XML

Its is working fine if I call each method one at a time by commenting other two method. Can anyone please help

php code sample($xml_request contains xml and it seems ok because I can execute without any error if I execute one method at a time by commenting any other two ):

```
$ch = curl_init($api_url);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $token.':123');

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, 'xml_request='.$xml_request);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 240);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Invoicera API Test 1.0");

$curl_result = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close ($ch);
return $curl_result;
```

Comment: are those three methods use same function that initiates curl connection?

Comment: Yes it uses a common function

Comment: do I understand you correctly: you're trying to post raw content of some xml file, but your API receiver can't parse your data?

Comment: Yes. I store xml data to one variable and pass this xml to server using curl then curl returns one value and using this value I am passing other xml data to server using curl and same for third request. but first request submitted successfully and second request returns "String could not be parsed as XML". but the same case if i send each request (one request at each execution) then all three returns success result.

Comment: can you show the signature of your function which parses xml that content?

Comment: I am sending curl request to invoicera.com  and server of invoicera will do further process of parsing and all .You can have a look at Inoicera api : http://www.invoicera.com/api.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/98338/discussion-between-bharat-and-romanperekhrest).